# Does irresistible force equal immovable object? What physics allow unsolvable paradoxes to exist?

Tags: physics

It is a common assertion that an irresistible force and an immovable object cannot exist in the same universe at the same time without ceasing to be irresistible or immovable.

However, is not an irresistible force and an immovable object logically the same thing? An immovable object cannot be changed from its current course, but if it is moving on its own then it would be an irresistible force to anything in its path. An irresistible force, if stationary, could not be moved from its position and would be an immovable object to anything trying to move it.

Therefore, if either an irresistible force or immovable object existed, then both would exist since they are one and the same. Since neither may coexist with the other, then neither can exist at all. Thus, an unsolvable paradox.

Is my logic sound? If so, what kind of physical laws (or absence thereof) would be required to allow such paradoxes to exist?

Comment: This seems to be a pure physics question, rather than a worldbuilding question. If you remove the last sentence (which would be overly speculative), I'd recommend trying [Physics Stack Exchange](http://physics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If an immovable object is moving, then it is not an immovable object, yes? An irresistible force is not an object, so cannot be at rest, yes? Seems like a simple misunderstanding of terms to me.

Comment: @Frostfyre: In what frame of reference? If it was sitting on a planet it would be moving with the planet's surface, but seem stationary to those standing next to it due to gravity. If the universe is moving around the immovable object, from the POV of the universe the "immovable" object is moving through the universe.

Comment: That just means there is no such thing as an immovable object in special relativity. Either that, or every object is immovable in its own reference frame.

Comment: This was discussed on philosophy stack. A lot, as far as I remember. And I don't see how this is about world building.

Comment: Good video for you to watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9eKc5kgPVrA

Answer (score 2):

It's all semantics.  If you choose to define your terms differently than others, you can get a different result than them.

The typical meaning of an "immovable object" is an object whose acceleration is always 0.  The typical meaning for an "irresistible force" is a force which, if applied to an object, always yields some non-zero acceleration.

What makes these phrasings difficult is that "irresistible force" is focused on how the environment responds to that force.  It's definition is actually not sufficient to describe the force on its own.

Needless to say, the application of an irresistible force to an immovable object, by these definitions, is paradoxically impossible.  However, if the irresistible force can never be applied to an immovable object, then no paradox occurs.  Your approach falls along this line.  The argument you are making is that the only irresistible force is a reactionary force coming from pushing on the immovable object.  Obviously the object cannot apply a reactionary force to itself, so you sidestep the paradox.

Of course, most people who try to use immovable objects and irresistible forces tend to choose to do so in a way that they interact, because that's where the interesting paradoxes occur.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming generally accepted physical laws apart from those explicitly removed, the problem here appears not to be that an unstoppable force and immovable object cannot exist at the same time but rather that neither an unstoppable force or an immovable object can ever exist, period.

In order to allow them to exist, we need to create a source of infinite energy or mass (these are equivalent by $e=mc^2$).

Let us imagine that an immovable object exists. This object must have infinite mass because otherwise, given a sufficient force, it would move (by Newton's second law). However, if an object has infinite mass, it also applies an infinite gravitational force to all objects. This will cause all objects to accelerate. Because this infinite force transfers infinite energy to these objects (every object in the universe) they will all accelerate to greater than the speed of light. This means that they will be *travelling backwards in time* (due to special relativity) at infinite speed, thus implying that every object in the universe exists in every position in the universe at once, travelling backwards in time. They would also gain an infinite mass (again due to $e=mc^2$) and thus then cause this same effect again.

This would violate basically all of the conservation laws, laws of thermodynamics and the Pauli exclusion principle. This is a very bad idea. And to top it all of, the infinite mass can be used to create an infinite number of similarly infinite masses (by Hilbert's hotel $\infty^2 = \infty$).

---

#### TL; DR

Any object of infinite mass (or any infinite energy source) would cause all objects in the universe to have infinite mass and all occupy every position in the universe simultaneously while all travelling backwards in time.

Comment: Remember Testicle's 1st Deviant to Fudd's Law: "If you push it hard enough, it will fall over."

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is that there is no such thing as an irresistible force, nor is there any such thing as an immovable object.

Let me explain.

1. There are two ways of understanding forces, as interactions in which energy is exchanged between objects, i.e. push and push-back and as fields, where the shape of some field, i.e. charge, magnetic, gravity, exerts a force on everything in the field.  The field is theoretical and always extends to infinity, but at large distances the effect can be considered negligible.
2. Any object that experiences a force will respond to that force, always, *it* never resists ( but *other* objects or forces my counteract the force in question ).
3. If, and only if, all the forces acting on an object add up to a net force with zero magnitude, then the object will not change its motion ( or will remain still ).

What this means in practice is that there can be many forces affecting an object and those forces can all be of different magnitudes and directions, but if all the magnitudes of all the forces in each of their directions results in a net force of zero magnitude, then the object remains on its current path.  If it was stationary and the net force on it is of zero magnitude, it will remain stationary.  If it is moving and the net forces on it are of zero magnitude, then its motion will not change.

Further, when and object's motion is viewed from a frame of reference that is external to any field that may affect the object, then the object may appear to travel in a non-straight path, but this is merely an observation that acknowledges a separate frame of reference than that of the field in which the object resides and is affected by.  For example in a gravitational field, a satellite *with no other forces affecting it* orbits a larger body in a circular path *because* that path *is in fact* a straight path, but it is the *space* that the object travels through which is curved from the external perspective.

#### Conclusion

The distinction, and the confusion, I think, is in how the idea of an object and the forces acting on it are two distinct phenomena.  An object is not a force, but can be affected by them.  And a force can be *applied* to an object but must be considered as either affecting the object internally ( as in molecular forces defining an object's structure ) or externally ( as in fields or other objects acting on an object ), but forces are not "part" of an object and cannot be "granted" to an object.